# How can I report an invalid login properly with Express and PassportJS?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js

I've successfully implemented passport-local into my Express/Mongoose web-app but I'm having trouble figuring out how to render a failed login message properly.

Here's my login route:

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
   res.render('user/login', {
   });
});
```

With a route like that how am I supposed to report an invalid login? If the login is successful it will write the `id`/`username` to the `req.user` object but that doesn't help me in the `"GET /login"` route because if it's successful you will get redirected to the page you want to go.

That means `req.user` will always be `undefined` when you `GET` the login page.

I want to be able to write out a message saying something like 'yo, invalid login!' when the following things happen:

1. The user does not exist.
2. The password supplied does not match but the user existed.

I might want to output a different message depending on what occurred.

When I implemented the LocalStrategy I used this code:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email'
},
function(email, password, fn) {
  User.findOne({'login.email': email}, function(err, user) {
    // Error was thrown.
    if (err) {
      return fn(err);
    }

    // User does not exist.
    if (!user) {
      return fn(null, false);
    }

    // Passwords do not match.
    if (user.login.password != utility.encryptString(user.login.salt + password)) {
      return fn(null, false);
    }

    // Everything is good.
    return fn(null, user);
  });
}
));
```

As you can see there are some problems but this is how the author of PassportJS set up his application. How are we supposed to access what the Strategy returns?

Like if it throws an error, what am I supposed to even call to get access to `err`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the custom callback or middleware functionality to have more control. See the [Authentication](http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate.html) section of the guide for examples.

For example, a *custom callback* might look like:

```
app.get('/login', function(req,res,next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err,user) {
            if(!user) res.send('Sorry, you\'re not logged in correctly.');
            if(user) res.send('Skeet skeet!');
    })(req,res,next);
});
```

Alternatively, you could always redirect both responses:

```
app.get('/login', 
    passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/winner',
                                     failureRedirect:'/loser' }));
```

Or redirect the failure with simple middleware:

```
app.get('/login', ensureAuthenticated,
    function(req,res) {
                // successful auth
                // do something for-the-win
    }
);

    // reusable middleware
    function ensureAuthenticated(req,res,next) {
        if(req.isAuthenticated()) {return next();}
        res.redirect('/login/again'); // if failed...
    }
```

Comment: Ah nice, the custom callback approach looks like it'll work. Thanks.

How would both alternative solutions do the same thing though? Wouldn't you do the success/failure redirect example on the POST request? That's what I'm doing atm.

And the second alternative one is just the standard way to enforce a login to access a page? Like, this is what you would put on a page you wanted to control access on (a user profile, etc.).

I'm going to mark you as the answer for the custom callback.

Comment: I took your question to be "how can I respond to authentication success or failure?", and these three methods are different ways of doing it. For the alternatives you're just sending the client to a different route to handle the response... since I don't know the specifics of your implementation it's up to you to decide what's best. Yes, option 3 is a great way to enforce auth for pages that require authentication.

Answer (score 17):

In the latest version of Passport, I've added support for flash messages, which make it easy to do what you are asking.

You can now supply a third argument to `done`, which can include a failure message.  For example:

```
if (user.login.password != utility.encryptString(user.login.salt + password)) {
  return fn(null, false, { message: 'yo, invalid login!' });
}
```

Then, set `failureFlash` to `true` as an option to `authenticate()`.

```
passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
                                 failureRedirect: '/login',
                                 failureFlash: true });
```

In this case, if authentication fails, the message will be set in the flash, ready for you to render it when you display the login page again.

Custom callbacks are also perfectly fine.  The built in options just make it simpler to accomplish common tasks.

Also, I'm curious: you mention that there are problems with the sample.  What do you think should be improved?  I want to make the examples as good as possible.  Thanks!

(For more details, see this [comment](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/12#issuecomment-4515135) on issue #12).

Comment: The failure flash makes it much easier. I did note however that any `err` passed to `done` or the OP's `fn` must be null or false for that work - took me a minute to realize that.